# How to redirect to the same/current page in Django?

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to develop a website for an online store with Django. For my view, when it adds a new product to the cart, I want to give a success message, but because I have pagination, it's always redirected to my home page, which is very annoying as a User.

When  I'm in my page=2, I want to add a product and stay at that page and not get redirected to the home page.

My views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, HttpResponseRedirect, Http404
from products.models import Product
from .models import Cart, CartItem
from django.contrib import messages
from django.urls import reverse
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe


def cart(request):
    try:
        the_id = request.session['cart_id']
    except:
        the_id = None
    if the_id:
        cart = Cart.objects.get(id=the_id)
        context = {"cart":cart}
    else:
        empty_message = "Your cart is empty, please keep shopping."
        context = {"empty": True, "empty_message": empty_message}

    template = 'shopping_cart/cart.html'
    return render(request, template, context)



def add_to_cart(request, slug):
    request.session.set_expiry(120000)
    try:
        qty = request.GET.get('qty')
        update_qty = True
    except:
        qty = None
        update_qty = False

    try:
        the_id = request.session['cart_id']
    except:
        new_cart = Cart()
        new_cart.save()
        request.session['cart_id'] = new_cart.id
        the_id = new_cart.id

    cart = Cart.objects.get(id=the_id)
    try:
        product = Product.objects.get(slug=slug)
    except Product.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404
    except:
        pass 

    cart_item, created = CartItem.objects.get_or_create(cart=cart, product=product)
    messages.success(request, f'Product added to Cart')
    return redirect('myshop-home')

    if update_qty and qty:
        if int(qty) == 0:
            cart_item.delete()
        else:
            cart_item.quantity = qty
            cart_item.save()
    else:
        pass
    # if not cart_item in cart.items.all():
    #     cart.items.add(cart_item)
    #     messages.success(request, mark_safe("Product added to cart. Go to <a href='cart/'>cart</a>"))
    #     return redirect('myshop-home')
    # else:
    #     cart.items.remove(cart_item)
    #     messages.success(request, mark_safe("Product removed from cart"))


    new_total = 0.00
    for item in cart.cartitem_set.all():
        line_total = float(item.product.price) * item.quantity
        new_total += line_total

    request.session['items_total'] = cart.cartitem_set.count()
    cart.total = new_total
    cart.save()

    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('cart'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this:

```
return redirect(request.path)
```

or:

```
return redirect(request.build_absolute_uri())
```

Comment: if I do ` return redirect(request.path) ` then it says redirected too many times